# SFML with C#, startup trouble

Tags: c#, .net, window, sfml

I want to use SFML with C# .NET. I've had to get SFML 2.0 since 1.6 apparently had some issues with AMD graphics cards. The issue is that the constructor of SFML.Window.Window enters an infinite loop.

My code:

```
using SFML;
using SFML.Window;
using SFML.Graphics;

namespace SFML
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            SFML.Window.Window window = new SFML.Window.Window(new VideoMode(800, 600), "Test widow");
        }
    }
}
```

It seems like nobody else on the internet has this issue, and I've tried it on another computer with the same result. Any help will be extremely appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure you're creating the `Window` appropriately.  Look at the examples from the Github source.  If you're doing OpenGL, you'd use `RenderWindow` for instantiating your window object:

https://github.com/SFML/SFML.Net/blob/master/examples/opengl/OpenGL.cs

For 2D windows:

https://github.com/SFML/SFML.Net/blob/master/examples/window/Window.cs

Also note the inclusion of `Tao` bindings in those examples.